# Cache Busting and Include Files for Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess

In Apache you can use the following to cache bust css and js files and server them as a single file with Apache's Include mod:

```
<FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
  Options +Includes
  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
  Options +Includes
  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I know this is possible with nginx but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

-- EDIT --
Adding some code

The only piece I have thus far is:

```
location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css)$ {
    ssi on;
    try_files $uri $1.$2;
}
```

What I'm looking for is to be able to combine all js and css files into single files using the `combined` keyword with a number for cache busting:

```
style.combined.100.css
javascript.combined.100.js
```

-- SOLUTION --

```
location / {

    ssi on;
    ssi_types *;

    location ~* \.combined\.js$ {
        ssi_types application/javascript application/json;
    }

    location ~* \.combined\.css$ {
        ssi_types text/css;
    }

    location ~* ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ {
        try_files $uri $1.$3 =404;
    }
}
```

Not sure how safe having `ssi_types *;` is ...

Comment: If someone's answer helped to arrive at the solution, remember to upvote and / or select it as the best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with the [ssi module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html), but could you give the following a try (more or less a direct rewrite of the Apache configuration).

```
location / {

    location ~* \.combined\.js$ {
        ssi on;
        ssi_types application/javascript application/json;
    }

    location ~* \.combined\.css$ {
        ssi on;
        ssi_types text/css;
    }

    location ~* ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ {
        try_files $uri $1.$3 =404;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well the cache busting part works. I'm calling my stylesheet as style.combined.100.css and it is linking to style.combined.css but sadly no ssi working. Still just printing out the includes:<!--# include file="stylesheet.css" -->
<!--# include file="megamenu.css" -->  etc.

Comment: Have you checked that your nginx is actually compiled with the SSI module. What's the output of `nginx -V`?

Comment: It is.  I created a test file and it is enabled. My version is latest stable nginx version: nginx/1.4.3 I wonder does this have to do the mime type of php that's delivered by fastcgi? I put the same ssi block `<!--#config timefmt="%A" --> <!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->` into a php file and it doesn't render. I'm thinking that even though the requested link is a .css file, it's being called by a php file so maybe it's not executing because ssi isn't active for the php mime type? Not sure what it is for php on fastcgi.

Comment: See updated question for solution.

Comment: This does work, I'm sure there must be a way to get it working without `ssi_types *` but I can't seem to find the right types to make it work.

Comment: You can add your desired MIME type to nginx's MIME configuration and only enable that type.